# Including spaces in Vigenere Cipher?

Tags: c++, encryption, vigenere

I am trying to create a program that will decode/encode the Vigenere Cipher. It works for all letters (A-Z) but I cannot figure out how to also include spaces in the cipher.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 
  
string generateKey(string str, string key) 
{ 
    int x = str.size(); 
  
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) 
    { 
        if (x == i) 
            i = 0; 
        if (key.size() == str.size()) 
            break; 
        key.push_back(key[i]); 
    } 
    return key; 
    
} 
  
// This function returns the encrypted text 
string cipherText(string str, string key) 
{ 
    string cipher_text; 
  
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) 
    { 
        // converting in range 0-25 
        char x = (str[i] + key[i]) %27; 
  
        // convert into alphabets(ASCII) 
        x += 'A'; 
        cout << cipher_text << endl;
        cipher_text.push_back(x); 
    } 
    return cipher_text; 
}
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate [How to Ingnore Spaces in Plain Text Vignere..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54727622/vigenere-cipher-how-to-ignore-spaces-in-the-plain-text-in-c#54727622)

Comment: There is something not right here. You should convert the character value of input and key to an index, then perform the encryption / decryption, and finally convert the ciphertext index back into a character. If you want to skip over the space you can do so, otherwise you will have to assign an index to the value 0x20 and then perform the mod 27. In other words, the space should be in the *alphabet* of the cipher.